# prevent copying content in a pdf that is created with dompdf

Tags: php, file, email, pdf, dompdf

is there a way to prevent the reciever from selecting and copying the contents of the pdf file in dompdf?

like those other pdf files that looks like a picture when you open it, all the letters and images are unselectable?

Comment: There are probably ways to do it, but they are *all* circumventable. Worst case: OCR will solve the problem. So just think about how badly you really need this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the underlying CPDF engine to specify what the user can do with the document. Per the CPDF documentation:

> Calling [the setEncryption()] function sets up the document to be
>   encrypted, this is the only way to mark the document so that they user
>   cannot use cut and paste, or printing.
>
> Using the call without options, defaults to preventing the user from
>   cut & paste or printing. There are no passwords require to open the
>   document.
>
> Setting either off the passwords will mean that the user will have to
>   enter a password to open the document. If the owner password is
>   entered when the document is opened then the user will be able to
>   print etc. If the two passwords are set to be the same (or the owner
>   password is left blank) then there is no owner password, and the
>   document  cannot be opened in the accesible mode.
>
> The pc array can be used to allow specific actions. The following
>   example, sets an owner password, a user password, and allows printing
>   and cut & paste.
>
> ```
> $pdf->setEncryption('trees','frogs',array('copy','print'));
> ```

Using the above example, with dompdf you would first render the document, then issue something along the lines of the following:

```
$dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption('trees','frogs',array('copy','print'));
```

([original on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dompdf-dev/IHnFkl7ejXw/wMFWFsNSStcJ))