# Dompdf -> Is it possible to render a pdf without copy select functions

Tags: php, dompdf

I generate a PDF with DOMPDF from my html design.
But i need to disable the copy + select function inside the pdf text.
I guess a jpg version of the html page would be a good solution inside the pdf but i'm not sure if this is possible.

Any idea or solution for rendering the pdf file non selectable (as a jpg maybe)

Below renders my A4 format html design:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($pdf_html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190294/prevent-copying-content-in-a-pdf-that-is-created-with-dompdf) and it works in Adobe Reader. The first two arguments are passwords, if you make them empty the document will open without a password.

However this copy prevention does not work, for instance, in the build-in PDF reader of Firefox. So **reliable protection from copying doesn't seem possible**.

However, now you know how you can password protect a file, and that could be a good solution as well? After all, if someone cannot access a PDF they cannot copy it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've found the password protection but it doesn't solve my isseu. The pdf is an insurance file so the legal viewer of the pdf may try to make changes on the pdf which i don't want to.

Comment: @hakanerenler: **Changing** a PDF is not the same as _"copying"_ or _"selecting"_. What you're looking for is [a signed PDF file](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/686). I haven't looked into that, but I will in the future. I think there's an useful answer under the link I just gave you. If you find a solution you can answer your own question.